# How to Clone a hard drive that has RAID-1 to another hard drive and make it bootable?

Tags: clone, raid-1

I am trying to clone a hard drive that is in RAID-1 and be able to boot that targeted hard drive.  I am using Win 7 and the hard drives are identical.  Acronis solution would not boot.  An image copy through the Windows program also would not boot.

Are there any ideas out there?

Comment: You will have to find a program, that supports clonning a RAID array, there isn't one built into Windows 7.  There appears to be [several](https://www.bing.com/search?q=clone+raid+array+windows&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) that can do the job though.

Comment: possible duplicate [here](http://superuser.com/questions/396642/how-do-i-clone-a-raid-0-array-to-a-single-disk).  You don't need reply to this comment If you disagree with my opionion that this question is a possible duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: Which RAID-1? I mean, is it HW RAID, "fake" RAID (BIOS/driver SW), a RAID made through Windows LDM?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it from within windows - RAID1 is just a mirror, so fire up a linux VM and use it to clone one of the RAID1 drives (if the drives are identical, this shouldn't be a big problem).

Guidance on cloning via linux here: http://lifehacker.com/5891933/the-best-disk-cloning-app-for-linux