# How to clone a single SSD to a 2 SSD RAID0?

Tags: ssd, clone, raid-0

This is the opposite to this: [How do I clone a RAID 0 array to a single disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/396642/how-do-i-clone-a-raid-0-array-to-a-single-disk)

I have a single SSD of 128GB, and I want to move it to 2x240GB SSD in RAID0.

The reason:
My windows is installed in one SSD of 128GB and I'm fighting a lot with the free space
I want to move everything to a bigger disk, without reinstalling anything, just replace the disk.
I guess is not problem with cloning the 128GB into another of 240GB, but I'm not sure what happen if I want to use 2 new 240GB ssd in RAID0, they must be empty and install everything from zero in that case or I can clone my current SSD into one of my new SSD and then configure the RAID0 without losing any data and without installing windows again?

Comment: What OS? What is driving the RAID0?

Comment: Windows 10, what do you mean driving the RAID0? I can setup that from the BIOS (MSI GS70 Stealth). Question edited to add more info