# Is it possible to clone a single disk from a Windows striped array ("RAID-0")?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, clone, software-raid, dynamic-disk

I know it's different for 'actual' RAID arrays, but I was wondering if maybe Windows striping / software RAID may be different, since all the striping happens within Windows and not a dedicated controller. Either way, I have tested 3 different backup tools and none of them were able to clone only a single drive from the dynamic disk array. I read something about block-level / low-level cloning but I have no experience with that so I thought I ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a RAID 0 array to a single disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/396642/how-do-i-clone-a-raid-0-array-to-a-single-disk)

Comment: Hello, Moab, thanks for the suggestion, but it's a fundamentally different issue. I'm trying to clone a SINGLE disk from a MULTI-disk fake-RAID array. One of the disks is failing and i want to swap it out without recreating the entire array / copying all the files. I just want to clone that failing disk to another healthy disk and swap it out.